# How do I combine the best of two Apps into one?

Tags: iphone, android

I have two similar iPhone and Android Apps (2 each) in the near future we will be combining/merging the best of these two Apps into one App. The App does have a user login that would need to be combined, but a common data file, so authentication should not be an issue. How do I deploy the combined App via the App Store and Google Market for users of the existing Apps? How can I phase the old out and let users know about the new merged App? I thought we could build the MOTHER App and deploy it as a version release in the App Store and Market, but can I deploy the same App version for two separate Apps? For the sake of an example, think of it as Bank of America merging their Apps with CitiBank under a single brand (CitiMobile is now BofA Mobile)

Thanks in advance your your valuable insight.

Comment: Given that the Apple and Google markets are utterly independent of each other, there's no rule that says you can't deploy v3.0 of the same-ish app in both stores.

Answer (score 0):

Merging two apps into one is actually quite simple in android do to the loosely coupled nature of the system. However, you may also consider remaining two apps that can talk to one another with a central content provider and broadcast intents, effectively using your own API.

If one app is the way to go, I would recommend making the super app and deploying it on the market, and deploy a "version" of the two original apps that informs the user what is going on and then points them to the Android Market for the super app.

The other way to do it is to deploy two copies of the super app one replacing each sub app, but that is way more hassle in the long run.

As far as iPhone goes, I can not speak to that.